# Condition in variation product template is not triggered correctly (ajax caching ?)

Tags: commerce

I have a commerce project with a specific product type using an attribute to generate variation.

Variation product has two specific fields that I want to hide switch attribute.

I implemented hook_preprocess_commerce_product to check this. In my hook, I check for a variation in POST (purchased_entity) or GET (v=xyz). If no one is found, I retrieve the default variation and set into the $variables array a new value called "is_custom_variation". This value is set to TRUE when the variation is a "custom" one. Only one variation in a product can be a custom variation, other are standard variations.

The "add to cart" form use a "select" form element to (ajax) switch between variations.

In the product template (commerce-product--full.html.twig) I added the following code :

```
<article{{ attributes }}>
{% if is_custom_variation %}
  {{- product|without('variation_attributes', 'variation_field_1', 'variation_field_2') -}}
{% else %}
  {{- product|without('variation_attributes') -}}
{% endif %}
</article>
```

Strange thing appears when I test the code :

- I load the product page with the default variation as "custom" variation : field 1 and field 2 are hidden. When I switch to another "non-custom" variation, fields are hidden too.
- I load the product page with a "non-custom" variation : field 1 and field 2 are displayed. When I switch to the "custom" variation, fields are displayed too.

By enabling xdebug, I see that each time the template is called, the variable "is_custom_variation" is correctly set (TRUE on custom variation, FALSE otherwise)

Maybe anyone can point me what is wrong on my implementation... I don't know why the template is using always the same process after the first display. Is it related to ajax reload of the variation ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other input data(url, query params, timestamp, cookie, etc) than $variables in your HOOK_preprocess you have to update your cache rules otherwise first time you get trough that hook will get cached for the rest of iterations of same $variables input.

In your case I suggest using cache context or cache tags where they change based on POST and GET variables.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the way it work, but render cache is not enabled, and the ajax call get a render array and process it. I tried a lot of combination to add cache contexts or tags to my render array in the preprocess function but result is always the same. I thank that using condition in twig template was the correct way to have a conditional display but maybe I'm wrong. Always is that I don't know how to change #cache key of my render array to achieve my goal. Other solution I see is to user JS with eventSubscriber on ProductEvents::PRODUCT_VARIATION_AJAX_CHANGE but seems hacky...